# Error while running Logic Apps (Standard)

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-logic-app-standard

I decided to ask here since the Logic Apps team won't answer me on github. Anyways, I have tried to run a logic app locally in VS Code following this guide: [Create Single Tenant Workflows Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code) (I have tried following other guides too) but I always get this same error when I run it:

```
Job dispatching error: operationName='JobDispatchingWorker.ExecuteTriggerInnerLoop', jobPartition='F106FDA38562443473E3DC4790D974E6:2D08585773452306434462235104894CU00', jobId='08585773234586434462235104894CU00', message='Job dispatching worker unable to execute inner trigger loop.', exception='System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type) 
  at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
  at Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.Common.Logging.FlowEventSource.JobHistory(String jobPartition, String jobId, String callback, String startTime, String endTime, String executionTimeInMilliseconds, String 
executionDelayInMilliseconds, String executionIntervalInMilliseconds, String executionStatus, String executionMessage, String executionDetails, String nextExecutionTime, String subscriptionId, String correlationId, String principalOid, String principalPuid, String tenantId, String dequeueCount, String advanceVersion, String triggerId, String messageId, String state, String organizationId, String activityVector, String realPuid, String altSecId, String additionalProperties, String jobDurabilityLevel)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Common.BackgroundJobs.Execution.JobDispatchingWorker.HandleJobExecution(JobTrigger trigger, JobDefinition definition, BackgroundJob backgroundJob, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, TimeSpan executionTime, TimeSpan executionDelay, TimeSpan executionInterval, JobExecutionResult executionResult, Boolean executeJobInline)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Common.BackgroundJobs.Execution.JobDispatchingWorker.ExecuteJobWithCancellation(JobTrigger trigger, JobDefinition definition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Common.BackgroundJobs.Execution.JobDispatchingWorker.ExecuteJobWithWatchdog(JobTrigger trigger, JobDefinition definition)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Common.BackgroundJobs.Execution.JobDispatchingWorker.ExecuteTriggerInnerLoop(JobTrigger trigger, JobDefinition definition)', correlationId='', organizationId='', activityVector='', additionalProperties='', extensionVersion='1.0.0.0', siteName='UNDEFINED_SITE_NAME', slotName='', activityId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.
```

The error occurs after

```
Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000051282CB2'
```

workflow.json (generated by vsc designer):

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "type": "ApiConnection",
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "office365"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "body": {
                        "To": "myEmail@something.com",
                        "Subject": "@triggerOutputs()?['body']?['name']",
                        "Body": "<p>@{triggerOutputs()?['body']?['name']} has been Updated</p>"
                    },
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {}
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_Added_or_Modified_in_Azure_Storage": {
                "type": "ServiceProvider",
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "path": "test/host"
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "AzureBlob",
                        "operationId": "whenABlobIsAddedOrModified",
                        "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {}
    },
    "kind": "Stateless"
}
```

connections.json

```
{
  "serviceProviderConnections": {
    "AzureBlob": {
      "parameterValues": {
        "connectionString": "@appsetting('AzureBlob_connectionString')"
      },
      "serviceProvider": {
        "id": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
      },
      "displayName": "sample"
    }
  },
  "managedApiConnections": {
    "office365": {
      "api": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/***/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/***/managedApis/office365"
      },
      "connection": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365"
      },
      "connectionRuntimeUrl": "https://***.**.common.logic-***.azure-apihub.net/apim/office365/***/",
      "authentication": {
        "type": "Raw",
        "scheme": "Key",
        "parameter": "@appsetting('office365-connectionKey')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=**********",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "WORKFLOWS_TENANT_ID": "***",
    "WORKFLOWS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID": "***",
    "WORKFLOWS_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME": "***",
    "WORKFLOWS_LOCATION_NAME": "***",
    "WORKFLOWS_MANAGEMENT_BASE_URI": "https://management.azure.com/",
    "AzureBlob_connectionString": "***********",
    "office365-connectionKey": "**********************************"
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your workflow it tries to parse a string as double and fails. Might be that the wrong data format is passed between workflow steps. Without seeing a minimal example of your workflow code it is hardly possible to say more.

Comment: I added a workflow.json file, it is however auto generated by the VSC extension via the logic app designer

Comment: The workflow looks fine. I can run the logic app here without issues. Can you tell us a bit more about your environment?

Comment: @ManuelBatsching I have all the necessary vs code extensions, (C#, Azure Account, Functions, Logic Apps (standard), Azurite. I also have Azure Functions Core Tools version 3.0.3477 (64-bit), .NET Core SDK 3.1.410, .NET runtimes: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.16, Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.16, Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.16 and lastly I have node.js v 12.*.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching I added connections, host and local.setttings.json files if that helps, please tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the Logic app itself and the problem lies within Azure Functions Core Tools and my country's way of using commas instead of dots. The problem was that my country uses , (comma) as a decimal separator and not . (dot). This caused the error and by changing my regional setting to the US, it works just fine.

Comment: What is your country?